# Is there a possibility of transmission of COVID-19 during sample collection process?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, test

Is there a possibility of transmission of COVID-19 during sample collection process from safety kits worn by sample collecting person to the suspected infected person whose sample is being collected?

I came across the following document on WHO website. https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/laboratory-biosafety-novel-coronavirus-version-1-1.pdf and it has links to following website that contains videos that demonstrate some lab procedures. http://who.int/ihr/publications/biosafety-video-series/en

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: First of all, I am not from medical background. I am merely interested in finding out about the safety procedures that get followed while collecting a test sample from a CovID19 suspect. The point about transmission from the safety kits worn by the person collecting sample to the person whose sample is being collected is not mentioned in the documents that I came across or I may have missed it due to my own lack of understanding perhaps. In any case, I wanted to know whether there is such a possibility of such transmission and what gets done to stop it or minimize it? Thanks!

Comment: "...is not mentioned in the documents that I came across..." I think would be better if you include such documents on your post.

Comment: I edited your question and added the links you provided. In the future when you're asked for more information, please edit your question and add it there instead of adding it to comments.